# disqus thread update API not working

Tags: drupal, disqus

I've hosted one `drupal` site in my local. In that site we have some migrated content from old same site with same domain. But problem is due to migration our content node ID ( always unique ) are changed. That's why `disqus` comments are also not appearing new site. So we want to update previous identifier to new migrated one. We have first tried through `disqus api` for thread update but it didn't work.

​After clicking on send request, we got the following message:

> "You must be authenticate to perform this action"

Comment: Did you succeed with it? I am facint the same exact problem, and disqus' staff only told me to update the threads' identifier using their API https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/update/ although I do not know how to use it or what to do

Comment: Not succeed till now. Still same issue is coming.